# No mxbeans found - MobileFirst Console

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, mxbean

I have installed MobileFirst Console at WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0.
Next I've installed my MobileFirst application. Unfortunately console shows message:

> No runtime enviroment deployed in this server.

I found these errors in logs:

> 000000ab WASRuntimeMBe I   Bean '*' does not exist.
>   000000ab RuntimeServic I   No mxbeans found
>
> SEVERE: Received status 500 for GET http://localhost:8080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
>   java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/loginAudit
>      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessor>Impl.java:57)
>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1676)

************ Start Display Current Environment ************

> WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.0 [BASE 8.5.5.0 gm1319.01] running with process name >localhostNode01Cell\localhostNode01\server1 and process id 19180
>   Host Operating System is Linux, version 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
>   Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
>   was.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
>   user.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01
>   Java Home = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre

Comment: There must me something wrong in the way you have installed the MF. Pls follow the instruction closely and make sure you haven't missed anything.

Comment: To get better support, please provide the following as described here:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21598161 --- For WAS: providea trace.log using "com.worklight.*=all" while recreating the problem.  Collect the files and directories in the install_dir/profiles/server_profile/logs directory, also collect the files and directories in the install_dir/profiles/server_profile/config directory.

Comment: I took a look at logs closely and I found response with status 500 from /loginAudit method. I've edited question and added it.

Comment: Anything else in the log? It'd be easier to .zip it all and upload to Dropbox or any other file sharing service.

Comment: The logs are required because the error you've added is missing the actual exception.

Comment: @RobertR, you've asked a question... please respond to the above.

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply enough information nor replied back to any of the additional questions asked.

Therefore I will assume you are using MobileFirst Server 7.0, which is not recommended to deploy on WebSphere 8.5.5.0; you should first upgrade to WebSphere 8.5.5.4 or 8.5.5.5 and re-deploy again. If failure occurs still, be more responsive and provide the requested information.